# Update datetime field 1.5 hours from another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 datetime fields in a single table.  dt1 and dt2.

dt1 has time data in it.

I need to run a query that updates dt2 to 1.5 hours ahead of dt1.

How can I update dt2 with a relative time to dt1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `dt2`= ADDDATE(`dt1`, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE);
```

Comment: The backticks aren't necessary - none of the field names are reserved words.

Comment: @marc B: table is a reserved word. @Sergej: I disagree with using backticks, they complicate (and look horrible) any long query, they allow using reserved words, which is a confusing and poor practice and peoples queries would be easier on the eyes and less confusing without those ugly backticks. UPDATE `INSERT` SET `INTO` = `FROM` WHERE `ORDER BY` = `INDEX` perfectly legal, good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function

> ADDTIME() adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result. expr1 is a time or datetime expression, and expr2 is a time expression.